# Reading data from socket with readv

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I'm having problems with a client-server communication made with writev()/readv().

I have two struct, `header` and `data` defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int op;
    int key;
} message_hdr_t;
typedef struct {
    int len;
    char *data;
} message_data_t;
```

The server does (in short):

```
message_hdr_t h = {1, 11};
message_data_t d;
d.len = 3;
strcpy(d.data, "msg");

struct iovec tosend[2];
tosend[0].iov_base = &h;
tosend[0].iov_len = sizeof(message_hdr_t);
tosend[1].iov_base = &d;
tosend[1].iov_len = sizeof(message_data_t);

writev(socket, tosend, 2);
close(socket);
```

The client (in short):

```
struct iovec received[2];
readv(socket, received, 2);
message_hdr_t header;
header.op = ((message_hdr_t *) received[0].iov_base)->op;
header.key = ((message_hdr_t *) received[0].iov_base)->key;
printf("Received op: %i, key: %i\n",header.op,header.key;
close(socket);
```

But the client gets a segfault because `received[0].iov_base` is `NULL`. Why?
The socket is correctly opened and the client is correctly connected to the server. It's an AF_UNIX socket.

Comment: What is `struct iovec`?

Comment: @alk It is a standard POSIX structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your server code, you are writing a *pointer*. This makes no sense. You don't want to transmit pointers over the wire. To transmit a string, you have to do something like this:

```
char* message = ...;
message_hdr_t h = {1, 11};

uint32_t message_length = strlen(message);

struct iovec tosend[3];

tosend[0].iov_base = &h;
tosend[0].iov_len = sizeof(message_hdr_t);

tosend[1].iov_base = &message_length;
tosend[1].iov_len = sizeof(message_length);

tosend[2].iov_base = message;
tosend[2].iov_len = message_length;
```

(You may want to move the string length to the message header and save one element of the vector, and make the protocol more readable).

Second, `readv` won't allocate memory for you, or divine out how many bytes you want to read. It's your job to correctly initialize `iov_base` and `iov_len` in the IO vector passed to `readv`. In order to read a dynamically-allocated variable-size string, you probably want to read twice. First, read a part of the message that contains the length of the string, then allocate the string, and read the rest of the message.